# Rails JSON request not reaching controller, most of the time

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having a hard time diagnosing the following problem. I have some server side tracking code, so we were passing a json request off to the controller when a download link is clicked. That triggers the server side tracking call.

The below code worked fine in staging on Heroku in Chrome. However when we went to production (mt), we started getting some weird behavior. If you click the download once in Chrome, no tracking. If you click twice, it tracks the second click. If you use IE11, it works like expected, generating a tracking event. If you use Firefox, it never works for production or staging.

We have played with a bunch of things with no results. Please help.

Rails 3.2.19 and Ruby 2.1.0

#### Thing Controller

```
def show
    authorize! :view, @thing, :message => "You do not have access to this thing. Is your subscription current?"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { track_event(current_user, "Viewed thing", {name: @thing.name}) }
      format.json do 
        track_event(current_user, "Downloaded thing", {name: @thing.name})
        render json: { :success => "success" }
      end
    end
  end
```

#### Thing show view

```
<div class="thing_label" data-container="<%= thing.name.parameterize %>-thing">
    <% if !thing.zip_file.blank? %>
        <%= link_to  (image_tag "cloud.png", height:'30', width:'30', :style => "vertical-align:top"), thing.zip_file, class: 'js-download-thing', title: "Download Thing", rel:"tooltip", data: {toggle:"tooltip", placement:"top", title:"Download Thing", thing_id: thing.id}  %>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <% end %>
    <%= thing.name.upcase %>
</div>
```

#### Application layout

```
    </div>
    </main>
    <%= render 'layouts/tracking' %>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Tracking partial

```
<script> $(function(){   $('.js-download-thing').click(function(){
    thing_id = $(this).data("thing-id")
    url = "<%= things_path %>/" + thing_id + ".json";
    $.get(url);   }) }) </script>
```

Comment: PS - I am using nearly the exact same pattern on a different object, and it works fine. The difference for that object is the rails server sends the downloaded object to the user, instead of directing them to an external link.

Answer (score 0):

That link sends the user to a new page, no?

So the tracking call needs to be completed before the link loads or it won't be called.

Maybe your production environment is just significantly faster so the call doesn't have time to load?

I would `return false;` on the link click and then send the user to the download link from a callback on that ajax request.

I might be totally off here, but in my experience I wasn't aware you could consistently process js after a link click without halting it on some level.

Comment: Yeah, you are right I think. We were trying to avoid having to route the request completely through the server so as to avoid delays that might cause the user to click the link repeatedly.

Comment: You could just disable the link when it is clicked. Or switch it to a loading indicator.

I also recommend using google analytics events for this kind of tracking, they're very lightweight and will likely reduce any delay your internal tracking is causing.